# KVC - check if the property exist

Tags: swift

Using Key Value Coding.
How do I write to check if the property exist?

```
let prop = state.value(forKey: "prop") as! Double
```

I tried the following code.

```
if !state.responds(to: Selector("getProp")) { ... } // always false
if state.value(forKey: "prop") != nil { ... } // the app crashed with 'NSUnknownKeyException' exception
```

Comment: try.. if let prop = state.value(forKey: "prop") as! Double {.....}

Comment: `getProp` is not the getter of a property `prop`. It's just `prop`.

Comment: ... and you get the exception if the property exists but is not key-value compliant.

Comment: The solution is to write `let prop = state.prop` and then the compiler will tell you if it exists or not.